# Bad File Number Socket Exception While Uploading file from server

Tags: android, file-upload, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am trying to upload file from android sdcard to FTP Web server. For this i am using Apache FTPClient library.
Here is my code to upload file ...

```
FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
                try
                {                       
                    con.connect("host ip",21);

                    int reply = con.getReplyCode();

                    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
                    {
                        con.disconnect();
                        System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }else{
                        System.err.println("FTP server connected");                         
                    }

                    if (con.login("username", "password"))
                    {
                        con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!

                        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/xmls/" + fileName);


                        boolean result = con.storeFile("/"+filename, in);

                        if (result){
                            Toast.makeText(DisplaySDCardContent.this, "File Uploaded Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                        }

                        in.close();
                    }
                }
```

While try to upload file ... i am getting exception that says bad file number .. socket exception...

```
    05-28 17:31:18.097: WARN/System.err(30486): java.net.SocketException: Bad file number
05-28 17:31:18.097: WARN/System.err(30486):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.writeSocketImpl(Native Method)
05-28 17:31:18.107: WARN/System.err(30486):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.write(OSNetworkSystem.java:723)
05-28 17:31:18.107: WARN/System.err(30486):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:578)
05-28 17:31:18.107: WARN/System.err(30486):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:59)
05-28 17:31:18.107: WARN/System.err(30486):     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:224)
05-28 17:31:18.107: WARN/System.err(30486):     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:113)
05-28 17:31:18.117: WARN/System.err(30486):     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:88)
05-28 17:31:18.117: WARN/System.err(30486):     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:61)
05-28 17:31:18.117: WARN/System.err(30486):     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:582)
05-28 17:31:18.117: WARN/System.err(30486):     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1702)
05-28 17:31:18.127: WARN/System.err(30486):     at com.mnp.webmanager.DisplaySDCardContent$2.onClick(DisplaySDCardContent.java:116)
05-28 17:31:18.127: WARN/System.err(30486):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-28 17:31:18.127: WARN/System.err(30486):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-28 17:31:18.127: WARN/System.err(30486):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-28 17:31:18.127: WARN/System.err(30486):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 17:31:18.127: WARN/System.err(30486):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-28 17:31:18.127: WARN/System.err(30486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-28 17:31:18.127: WARN/System.err(30486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 17:31:18.137: WARN/System.err(30486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-28 17:31:18.137: WARN/System.err(30486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-28 17:31:18.137: WARN/System.err(30486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-28 17:31:18.137: WARN/System.err(30486):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i stuck here and passed a lot time to solve this but no solution yet i found.
Please help with this .
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the Apache FTPClient 3.0.1. It seems like there was bug in the 3.0.

https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/commons-net/commons-net/3.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

Cheers,

Comment: yahh ... i also think so ... coz after firing this exception, it was uploading file to my ftp server that i was not knowing ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct permissions in your Android Manifest:

Confirm that the server IP is correct and that a listening socket exists on the other end.  You have "host ip" but I am assuming that is obfuscating your actual server IP.  Make sure you can connect to that machine from something other than your phone.

Comment: listing sockets on other end ? what should be there on other hand for that ? i don't know about that. Do you know why this exception occurs or if you have any other better tutorial about uploading file from android mobile to server using ftp. thanks for your reply.